# Sending an array to php from JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [send arrays of data from php to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290720/send-arrays-of-data-from-php-to-javascript)

I know there are many questions like this but I find that none of them are that clear.

I have an Ajax request like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "parse_array.php",
    data: "array=" + array,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.reply);
    }
});
```

How would I send a JavaScript array to a php file and what would be the php that parses it into a php array look like?

I am using JSON.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Step 1

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "parse_array.php",
    data:{ array : JSON.stringify(array) },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.reply);
    }
});
```

## Step 2

You php file looks like this:

```
<?php 



  $array = json_decode($_POST['array']);
    print_r($array); //for debugging purposes only

     $response = array();
     if(isset($array[$blah])) 
        $response['reply']="Success";
    else 
        $response['reply']="Failure";

   echo json_encode($response);
```

## Step 3

The success function

```
success: function(data) {
        console.log(data.reply);
        alert(data.reply);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks alot for prompt answer :)

Comment: You'd want to URL-encode the result from `JSON.stringify`, i'd think, so a stray `&` in one of your object's strings wouldn't cut your string off prematurely and break your JSON.

Comment: @cHao Agreed, I've changed it slightly to use the object notation, which will force jQuery to handle the URLencoding so that you can ignore

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass a javascript object.

JS:

```
var array = [1,2,3];
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "parse_array.php",
    data: {"myarray": array, 'anotherarray': array2},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.reply); // displays '1' with PHP from below
    }
});
```

On the php side you need to print JSON code:

PHP:

```
$array = $_POST['myarray'];
print '{"reply": 1}';
```

Answer (score 0):

HI,

use `json_encode()` on **parse_array.php**

and retrive data with `json_decode()`

Comment: why would i encode the array in php? I want to use it in php.

Comment: yes i know how to send json back to jquery. and that was not my question.