# AJAX jquery json sending array to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to send a associative array via AJAX $.post to php. Here's my code:

```
var request = {
        action: "add",
        requestor: req_id,
        ...
    }

    var reqDetails = $("#request_details").val();

    switch(reqDetails){
        case 1: 
            request[note] = $("#note").val();
            break;

        ...

    }

    if(oldRequest()){
        request[previousID] = $("old_id").val();
    }

    $('#req_button').toggleClass('active');
    $.post("scripts/add_request.php", {
        request_arr: JSON.stringify(request)
        }, function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $('#req_button').toggleClass('active');
    }, 'json');
```

And i'm simply trying to read the received data in my php script:

```
echo json_decode($_POST["request_arr"]);
```

But it's not working. I'm a newbie to js, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify(request)`

Comment: The undefined variables `note` and `previousID` should probably be strings `"note"` and `"previousID"`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that @James. I've changed the code now, but I still get the same problem. I even tried Deeban's answer, but It isn't working for me.

Answer (score 3):

Check below link for your reference

[Sending an array to php from JavaScript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255533/sending-an-array-to-php-from-javascript-jquery)

## Step 1

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "parse_array.php",
    data:{ array : JSON.stringify(array) },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.reply);
    }
});
```

## Step 2

You php file looks like this:

```
<?php 



  $array = json_decode($_POST['array']);
    print_r($array); //for debugging purposes only

     $response = array();
     if(isset($array[$blah])) 
        $response['reply']="Success";
    else 
        $response['reply']="Failure";

   echo json_encode($response);
```

## Step 3

The success function

```
success: function(data) {
        console.log(data.reply);
        alert(data.reply);
    }
```

Comment: I tried this, but I'm getting "POST http://server/add_request.php 500 (Internal Server Error)" .
Its at the line "$array = json_decode($_POST['array']);"

Answer (score 0):

You are already using "**json**" as dataType, so you **shouldn't** apply 'stringify' operation on your data.

Instead of `request_arr: JSON.stringify(request)`, can you try `request_arr: request` directly?

Comment: Can you edit your PHP Code with " print_r($_POST);" and share result?